# js function to work onLoad with onClick in cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

In cakephp the below code works fine when I load a page and select an option to enable/disable textfields.

The problem is that when I refresh the page  when I click a cakephp button elsewhere, the textfields are enabled again that were previously set to disabled.

How do I cater for the disabled textfields when page refreshing?

```
window.onload=function(){
       if(val != 3) {
        document.getElementById("startdatebox").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("enddatebox").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("startdatebox").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("enddatebox").disabled = false;
    }

    } ​ 

   function myFunc(val) {
    if(val != 3) {
        document.getElementById("startdatebox").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("enddatebox").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("startdatebox").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("enddatebox").disabled = false;
    }

 //  alert( document.getElementById("dateRange").value);

}

...
       echo $this->Form->input('startDate',array('id'=>'startdatebox','label' => 'Start Date','class'=>'datepicker', 'type'=>'text','style'=>'width:100px;height:30px','value' => $datestart));

 echo $this->Form->input('endDate',array('id'=>'enddatebox','label' => 'End Date','class'=>'datepicker', 'type'=>'text','style'=>'width:100px;height:30px','value' => $dateend));




    $selectoption=array(1=>'Today',0=>'Fortnight',2=>'Monthly',3=>'Custom Range'); 
       echo $this -> Form -> input('dateRange', 
               array('id'=>'dateRange2','label' => '<h6>Date Range</h6>','type' => 'radio', 
              'value' =>$dateSelect,'options' =>  $selectoption,  'onclick'=> 'myFunc(this.value)'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution using jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var val = $("input[type=radio][name='dateRange2']:checked").val();
    if(val!=3) {
        $('#startdatebox,enddatebox').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

**instead of**

```
window.onload=function(){
   if(val != 3) {
      document.getElementById("startdatebox").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("enddatebox").disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("startdatebox").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("enddatebox").disabled = false;
    }

}
```

Don't forget to load  [jquery library](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/04/jquery-1-9-1-released/) also.

Comment: var val = $("input[type=radio][name='dateRange2']:checked").val(); this is display undefined BTW and doesnt work

Comment: `$dateSelect` should be an integer value, not an a array.

Comment: $dateSelect is an array as how else can cakephp get the values in a group?

Comment: you should set the value for `$dateSelect` in controller.